# Passed array to php from jquery with ajax value just shows Array not actual array value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

Please can someone tell me where I'm going wrong
js file:

```
//Checkboxid is an array which is populated using .push();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    dataType: 'html',
    data: { data: Checkboxid },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);

    }
});
```

test.php:

```
<?php
 $test = $_POST['data'];
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($test); ++$i) {
        echo $test[$i];
    }

    foreach($test as $val) {
    echo $val;
}
?>
```

console.log displays:

> ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray

Comment: what is result of `var_dump($test)`

Comment: array(26) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(28) "Adverse_Weather_Conditionsv1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(21) "Bank_Holiday_Policyv1"
  }

Comment: If I do    for (var i = 0; i < Checkboxid.length ; i++) {
   console.log(Checkboxid[i]);
} just before the ajax it displays fine.

Comment: what is the result of console.log(checkboxid) in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$test` variable is a two-dimensional array. Try this

```
<?php
   $test = $_POST['data'];

  foreach($test as $arr) {
     foreach($arr as $val){
          echo $val;
     }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Haha Thank you so much I started coding this last night came back to it this morning I completely forgot it was 2D. I thought I was going insane.

Comment: You should always think about dimensional arrays when your print tests are "Array" :)